# Jquery and frame click event

Tags: jquery, click, frame, frameset

I want to make an auto-click event for frame 1 after 4 seconds when link.php is loaded. My code for Link.php is

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Source</title>
<script type='text/javascript' src="js/jquery-1.5.2.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
$(function() {
    $('[alt="Skip"]').click(function(){});
    setTimeout(function(){$('[alt="Skip"]').trigger('click');}, 4e3);
});
});//]]>  
</script>
</head>
<frameset rows="200px,*" style="width:100%">
        <frame src="skip.php" frameborder="0" name="frame1" />
        <frame src="http://xyz.com" frameborder="0" />
</frameset><noframes></noframes>
</body>
</html>
```

code inside skip.php

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<a href="http://www.example.com/"><img src="images/skip.png" border="0" alt="Skip"></a>
</body>
</html>
```

The javascript code is working when its pasted inside skip.php but I want to work it inside link.php

Comment: What is 4e3 in the set timeout function in link.php?

Comment: its the 4 sec timeout function

Comment: Inside skip.php alt="skip" not alt="Skip this Advertisement"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The working script is

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$($('frame[name="frame1"]')[0].contentWindow).load(function() {
var documentOfFrame = $('frame[name="frame1"]')[0].contentDocument;

   $('[alt="Skip"]',documentOfFrame).click(function(){});
   setTimeout(function(){$('[alt="Skip"]',documentOfFrame).trigger('click');}, 4e3);
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify frame's document as a context for `jQuery()` selector:

```
$(function() {
   //Waiting till the frame's hierarchy will be constructed
   $(frames['frame1']).load(function() {
      var documentOfFrame = this.contentDocument;

      $('[alt="Skip"]',documentOfFrame).click(function(){});
      setTimeout(function(){$('[alt="Skip"]',documentOfFrame).trigger('click');}, 4e3);
   });
});
```

See [**"Selector Context"**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) section.

Comment: @user1502071 Try these `$(document).ready(function(){ $($('frame[name="frame1"]')[0].contentWindow).load(function(){  alert('frame is loaded');   }); });` and `$(window).load(function(){  alert('main content is loaded');   });`. Then tell me the sequence that `alert`s are triggered.

Comment: @user1502071 Try to replace `alert('frame is loaded');` by my answer's code (without `$(function() {})` of course).

Comment: @user1502071 I have provided cross-browser and more elegant solution.See my update.